# CMake project with CPP and ASM

Tags: c++, macos, assembly, cmake, x86

Try to make hello world project with external ASM function in CPP.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

project(TestProject VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX ASM)

set_property(SOURCE foo.s APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_OPTIONS "-x" "assembler-with-cpp")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

add_executable(TestProject main.cpp foo.s)

target_include_directories(TestProject PUBLIC
              "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"
              )
```

foo.s

```
.text
.globl _foo
_foo:
add %esi, %edi // add x and y
mov %edi, %eax // move result to correct register for return value
ret
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int foo(int x, int y);

int main() {
  int result = foo(100, 200);
  cout << result << endl;
}
```

I can generate project for my IDE successfully

```
cmake .. -G Xcode
```

And if I build it in IDE I get this error:

```
Error 
Undefined symbol: foo(int, int)
```

And if I try to build from terminal

```
cmake --build ..
```

I get error with CMakeCache.txt:

```
Error: could not load cache
```

CPP (only) projects builds fine on the machine.
Suppose something wrong with generated CMakeCache.txt but can get it.

CMakeCache.txt:
https://pastebin.com/BSbZfA67

Comment: the cmake command you've used sets up the project in the current working directory and the directory where you set up the project needs to be passed via `--build`, i.e. you should have used `cmake --build .` instead of `cmake --build ..`, assuming you haven't changed the working directory. This wouldn't change the linker results though.

Comment: @fabian dont mention it, but i run cmake commands from the scripts folder. Anyway cmake --build . in root project folder gets Error: could not load cache

Comment: Assuming you've successfully configured the project, cmake has created a `CMakeCache.txt` file in some directory. The error message you're receiving indicates that this is missing from the directory passed via `--build`. There's one more thing that strikes me as odd: usually the source directory is passed as the last parameter to the cmake generation. Are you sure the configuration completed successfully? Btw: my personal perferrence is using`-S`+`-B`e.g. `mkdir build_dir && cmake -G Xcode -S . -B build_dir && cmake --build build_dir` to set up&build the project in the current dir in build_dir

Comment: @fabian u save my evening :) with mkdir build_dir && cmake -G Xcode -S . -B build_dir && cmake --build build_dir everything generates and builds from terminal fine. Ofc its my fault with bad cmake .. -G Xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `foo` to have C++ linkage but defined it to have C linkage.  To fix this problem, declare `foo` to have C linkage instead:

```
extern "C" int foo(int x, int y);
```

Comment: Thank u! But extern "C" int foo(int x, int y); with return value.
It doesnt debug in IDE, but at least builds.

Comment: @k.makarov What happens when you try to debug this?

Comment: after i clean and regenerate the project debug in IDE works fine too. Thanks!